# Why are my variable or cast empty in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm coding an app on Xcode for IOS and I'd like to send a variable to another ViewController that hasn't appeared yet. The problem is that when I make a variable of my future ViewController like this :

```
guard let EndConfiguration = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: EndConfiguration) as? EndConfiguration else
        {
            fatalError("Impossible d'acceder correctement au cellules des alarmes")
        }
```

And I'm trying to do this:

```
EndConfiguration.ModeleOutlet.text = Alarme.shared.Alarmes[indexPath.row].Modele
```

I get this error :

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
> Optional value

I understood the Optionels but if I add a "?" after ModeleOutlet it will remove the error but the text remains unchanged in my other ViewController. I'm sure that the value I modify is full, don't worry.

I'm replicating my problem because someone close it because there was already a solution when there wasn't one at all.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 
guard let EndConfiguration = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: EndConfiguration) as? EndConfiguration else
        {
            fatalError("Impossible d'acceder correctement au cellules des alarmes")
        }
_ = EndConfiguration.view
EndConfiguration.ModeleOutlet.text = Alarme.shared.Alarmes[indexPath.row].Modele
```

Comment: Thanks for your responce, Indeed the fact of having added your command line does not give me any more error about the optional. But unfortunately I still can't modify my variable or my Outlet. If I print my variable "EndConfiguration" i get : "<Alarme.EndConfiguration: 0x7fa97fc49690>", It's good ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am making the assumption that type of `ModeleOutlet` is a `Label` or of another type that may contain a text variable.

If **ModeleOutlet** is indeed a label that is attached via storyboard, then I urge you to read up on the ViewController lifecycle. Here is a great article describing it : https://medium.com/good-morning-swift/ios-view-controller-life-cycle-2a0f02e74ff5

Now, to answer your question specifically, you'll likely want to create a separate variable within your view controller then set the text variable within the function, `viewDidLoad`.

```
class EndConfiguration: UIViewController {
    public var sharedText: String?

    @IBOutlet var ModeleOutlet: UILabel?

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.ModeleOutlet?.text = sharedText
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I read what you sent me and thank you very much it enlightened me. So I did that in my EndConfiguration: https://ibb.co/6FRdh4K .
And in my "step 1" : https://ibb.co/nsSLJSx .
But it still doesn't work, did I make a mistake? 
Thank you for your peace of mind.

Comment: @LouisRaverdy It appears that you may need to connect your `@IBOutlet` to the storyboard itself. [https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html)

Comment: Yes in my EndConfiguration there was already a @IBOulet of my label I need to add another one ?

Comment: @LouisRaverdy I see that the `@IBOutlet` for `ModeleOutlet` is created. Can you verify that it is connected to the storyboard?

Comment: After checking it works very well:  https://ibb.co/7YNpFNt and https://ibb.co/5kSLM61

Comment: @LouisRaverdy Make sure to hit that accepted answer and upvote button! ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misspoke. I just wanted to prove to you that my Outlet is working well.

Comment: @LouisRaverdy Understood. Are you using segues?

Comment: No I haven't learned this yet, is this recommended?

Comment: @LouisRaverdy Well, in the class `ETape`, you in call `instantiateViewController`, but do not push to that screen after pressing the table cell. I can only assume, you've wired your  screen directly with a segue in your storyboard.

Comment: You may try and look into the prepare function for use in `ETape` : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare. Something like this? ```override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.destination is EndConfiguration
    {
        let vc = segue.destination as? EndConfiguration
        vc?.sharedText = "Hello World"
    }
}```

Comment: Ok, first of all thank you for your patience and help. I tried the Segue but it doesn't work. The problem comes necessarily from the reference of my variable but where is the error? And how can I give you more information?

Comment: I tried to make a schematic very quickly to show you my storyboard : https://ibb.co/Cb3Pz8J

Comment: You'll need to pass the sharedText from `Etape1` to `Etape2`, then finally `EndConfiguration` using the prepare function listed above.

Comment: I tried to do this but I can't even get from Etape 1 to Etape 2. https://ibb.co/GHZ3Gj6 and https://ibb.co/3pRmyrg